# Get all parents and children of a tree recursively

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, recursion

I have a MySQL table as

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|        Id          |      parent_id     |        title       |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|        1           |         0          | Student Management |
|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
|        2           |         0          |  Staff Management  |
|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
|        3           |         1          |     Add Student    |
|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
|        4           |         1          |    View Students   |
|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
|        5           |         2          |      Add Staff     |
|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
|        6           |         2          |      View Staff    |
|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
|        7           |         4          |       Delete       |
|--------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
|        8           |         5          |        Copy        |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

**I want to get above as in my view recursively as.**

**Desired Output**

```
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+
|      Student Mangement        |         Staff Management     |
|        Add Student            |            Add Staff         |
|       View Student            |              Copy            |
|          Delete               |            View Staff        |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

I want to get above MySQL table as structure I defined above

My get method is as

```
public function get()
{
    $categories = Categories::where('parent_id', '=', 0)->get();
    $permission = Categories::pluck('title','id')->all();
    return view('create-role')->with(compact('categories'));
}
```

With above method, i am getting parents in y view as

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
   <li>
     {{ $category->title }}
   </li>
 @endforeach
```

Output is as

Student Management

Staff Management

Please Help how can I get above-mentioned structure recursively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First define the relationships in your model

```
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function parent() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

Then in your view, I don't know how many sub levels you have. But there are 2 ways:

1- The easiest way

If you know, you will never go over 3 levels, just nest 3 foreach in your view

First you query eagerly

```
$categories = Category::with('children')->get(); //save you some queries 

@foreach($categories as $category)
    @if( $category->children )
        @foreach($category->children as $level2)
            @if($level2->children)
               @foreach($level2->children as $level3)
                   @if($level3->children)
                       //another foreach
                   @endif
                   {{ $level3->title }}
               @foreach
            @endif
            {{ $level2->title }}
        @endforeach
    @endif

    {{ $category->title }}
@endforeach
```

2- The actual recursive way.

This is experimental and not tested

Define a recursive relationship

```
public function recursiveChildren() {
    return $this->children()->with('recursiveChildren');
    //It seems this is recursive
}
```

Comment: Keep nesting. how I did for level2

Comment: I think with the second method, you still need to use multiple foreach in the view to display. Because querying is one thing, displaying is another. You cannot display all of them in one go. Sorry for not being helpful, I hope someone else finds something better.

Comment: That is the relationship between parent and children. Read abour relationships here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple recusive way to do it with php (any framework).

Basically you need all of the items in a simple array and run formatTree, but you can change the function to use object instead of array.

```
<?php

function formatTree($tree, $parent)
{
    $tree2 = array();
    foreach ($tree as $item) {
        if ($item['parent_id'] == $parent) {
            $tree2[$item['id']] = $item;
            $tree2[$item['id']]['child'] = formatTree($tree, $item['id']);
        }
    }

    return $tree2;
}


//for demo
$beforeTree = [
    ['id' => 1, 'parent_id' => 0],
    ['id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 1],
    ['id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 2],
    ['id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 0],
    ['id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 4],
    ['id' => 6, 'parent_id' => 4],
];
$afterTree = formatTree($beforeTree, 0);

var_dump($afterTree);
```

Comment: tree array. you can run it in any online php sandbox

Comment: ok i will try it please a little explain what is $item and what will be $parent...
I mean working of code

Comment: confusion is about $parent at start of if condition and its also gives error about format method   Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\formatTree()

Comment: item is name of variable used in the loop. You can name it as you wish it doesn't matter what name it'll be.

parent is used for recursion function. On first call you call it with zero. It's special indicator for this function

Comment: thanks please also explain about $parent and error i mentioned in above comment

Comment: If you use this function in the class you need to call function with $this
for example $this->formatTree

Comment: its error here within loop $tree2[$item['id']]['child'] = formatTree($tree, $item['id']);

Comment: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\formatTree()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137984/discussion-between-recovery-men-and-auct).