# Trouble with Eloquent getting all children

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel and Eloquent, I need to get all the children ID from parent ID.

These are my sample data:

```
ID  Entity Name Amount  Parent ID   Data Level  Currency<br>
1   Great Grandpa_1 0   0       1       php<br>
2   Great Grandpa_2 10000   0       1       php<br>
3   Great Grandpa_3 20000   0       1       php<br>
4   Grandpa_1   5000    1       2       php<br>
5   Grandpa_2   6000    1       2       php<br>
6   Grandpa_3   7000    1       2       php<br>
7   Grandpa_4   1000    2       2       php<br>
8   Grandpa_5   2000    2       2       php<br>
9   Grandpa_6   3000    2       2       php<br>
10  Grandpa_7   0   3       2       php<br>
11  Dad_1       1500    4       3       php<br>
12  Dad_2       2500    4       3       php<br>
13  Dad_3       3500    4       3       php<br>
```

This is my script in MySQL:

```
select group_concat(lv separator ',') as children from 
(select @pv := (select group_concat(id separator ',') from 
tbljournalentry where parent_id in (@pv)) as lv from 
tbljournalentry join (select @pv := {$id})tmp where parent_id in (@pv))a;
```

This is as far as I can go:

```
$result = DB::table('tbl_journalentry')->where('parentid', $id)->get();
```

I can only get the immediate child. I need to get all the children IDs. 
I hope you can explain to me what I needed to do. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all parents and children of a tree recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779256/get-all-parents-and-children-of-a-tree-recursively)

Answer (score 0):

use [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck)

```
$result = DB::table('tbl_journalentry')->where('parentid', $id)->pluck('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get all the data from great granparent to children.

first you need to find ID of all grandparents.

```
$greatgrandpa = DB::table('tbl_journalentry')->where('parentid', 0)->pluck('id');
```

It will return all IDs for great grandpa. Now loop through it to get all ID of grandpa.

```
$grandpa = DB::table('tbl_journalentry')->whereIn('parentid', $arrayofgreatgrandpaIDs)->pluck('id');
```

you will have all grandpa IDs. Now again find Dad Ids using IDs of grandpa.

```
$dad = DB::table('tbl_journalentry')->whereIn('parentid', $arrayofgrandpaIDs)->pluck('id');
```

By this you can fetch all the level of childs.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

I assumed that your model name is `journalentry` and add below code in `journalentry` model

**In Model**

```
public function children() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\journalentry','parentid','id');
}
```

**In Controller**

```
use App\journalentry;//Model name

$result = journalentry::find($id);
print_r($result->childs);
foreach ($result->childs as $data) {
   print_r("*******sub child***** <br>");
   print_r($data->childs);
}
```